# Can't decode Json using Plug.Parsers with Elixir

Tags: elixir

I am trying to build an endpoint with Elixir and Plug that should receive Json from Github, but for reasons I don't understand the body_params are always empty:

```
defmodule Endpoint do
  import Plug.Conn

  require Logger

  use Plug.Builder

  plug Plug.Parsers, parsers: [:json], json_decoder: Jason

  def init(options), do: options

  def call(conn, _opts) do
    Logger.debug inspect(conn)
    conn
      |> put_resp_content_type("text/plain")
      |> send_resp(200, "Welcome Github!\n")
  end
end
```

My understanding of the Plug.Parsers documentation is that it should fetch and decode the Json body and I should have a data structure under body_params, but quite clearly I'm missing something.
If I

```
{:ok, body, conn} = Plug.Conn.read_body(conn)
```

body contains the Json.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `super` method to call the plug chain you listed like `Plug.Parsers`.

Besides, use `conn.body_params` instead of `Plug.Conn.read_body` because 
`Plug.Parsers` [**will read the body**](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#read_body/2) so the body is unavailable after being accessed.

After process, `Plug.Parsers` will have `:body_params` [set to the map of params parsed by parsers](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Parsers.html), which is a result of merging the `:body_params` and `:query_params`.

```
defmodule TestPlug do
  import Plug.Conn
  require Logger

  use Plug.Builder

  plug Plug.Parsers, parsers: [:json], json_decoder: Jason

  def init(options), do: options

  def call(conn, opts) do
    conn =  super(conn, [])
    IO.inspect conn.body_params
    conn
      |> put_resp_content_type("text/plain")
      |> send_resp(200, "Welcome Github!\n")
  end
end
```

> The call/2 function that Plug.Builder provides is used internally to
>   execute all the plugs listed using the plug macro, so overriding the
>   call/2 function generally implies using super in order to still call
>   the plug chain[2](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Builder.html#content)